# NoMachine behind a NAT

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-management, xforwarding, remote-control

My provider uses a NAT network. I would like to expose a NoMachine server over the WAN (like I do with TeamViewer). When starting the server,   I only get a list of private IP addresses, which are not usable on the client side. I read about an [anywhere service](https://mintguide.org/tools/print:page,1,359-nomachine-free-impressive-utility-for-remote-desktop.html).
How can I use that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something nasty (assuming you do not need to contact the external IP from the NoMachine server) and add the external IP to the loopback device (or, if that is not enough, to eth0). Then the address should appear in the list for the client.

You could even run NoMachine in a network namespace so that it sees only the external IP. On the real interface you would do DNAT and route those packets to the namespace.

Comment: "assuming you do not need to contact the external IP from the NoMachine server". Well, I need to remote manage my PC away from home. Also, if I try to connect to my home PC from a hotel, on the road, etc., I do not know in advance what IP I'll be given.